# Verificação de input do tipo radio com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Boa noite pessoal, estou enfrentando uma dificuldade aqui e não consigo resolver.

Eu tenho uma pagina de checkout onde exibo dois meios de pagamento, boleto e cartão, as opções para o usuário selecionar se prefere boleto ou cartão são dois campos do tipo radio. Segue o html.

```
<section class="campaign-details-wrap">

    <div class="container">
                  {!! Form::open(['id' => 'form']) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
                            <h4 class="mb-3">Pagamento</h4>
                            <label for="amount" class="font-weight-bold">Valor</label>
                            <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="" maxlength="12" required/>
                            </div>{{--#Col --}}

                    </div>{{--#Row --}}
                </div>{{--#Form-group --}}


                <hr class="mb-4">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-0 mt-0">
                            <input id="paymentCheck" name="paymentMethod" value="billet" type="radio" checked> 
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="paymentCheck">Boleto</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>{{--#Row --}}

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-0 mt-0">
                            <input id="paymentCheck" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" value="card" class="name_display_wrap">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="paymentCheck">Cartão</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>{{--#Row --}}

                </div>{{--#Form-group --}}


        {!! Form::close() !!}

        <a href="" class="btn-finished">Finaliza Pagamento</a>

    </div>

</section>
```

Eu preciso executar algumas ações em jQuery, porém cada ação dessas depende do meio de pagamento selecionado.

Eu preciso fazer selecionar o input/radio, pegar o valor desse radio pra depois executar a ação, mas não estou conseguindo pegar o valor do input/radio se foi boleto ou cartão pra executar a ação, alguém sabe como fazer isso em jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode ter dois elementos com o mesmo ID no formulário. Suas opções de radio devem ter o mesmo nome, mas não o mesmo ID.

Alterando isso, é possível pegar o valor do radio pelo nome, assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#mostrar').click(function () {
      alert($('input[name=paymentMethod]:checked').val());
   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
   <input id="paymentCheckBillet" name="paymentMethod" value="billet" type="radio" checked> 
   <label class="form-check-label" for="paymentCheck">Boleto</label>
</p>
<p>
   <input id="paymentCheckCard" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" value="card" class="name_display_wrap">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="paymentCheck">Cartão</label>
</p>
<button id="mostrar">Mostrar escolha</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação com relação a id, mas eu preciso fazer um if, por exemplo, if radio boleto foi selecionado, executar ação, else outra ação.

Comment: Ok, então só precisa disso:  `if($('#paymentCheckBillet').is(':checked'))`

Comment: Valeu Ricardo, muito obrigado era o que eu precisava.